# Creating buttons that event handle with a visual c++ program

Tags: xml, visual-c++, windows-ce, device-emulation

I will try to explain this the best that I can. I currently have a program that at the moment just cycles through menus by clicking some button graphics that I have created. I am also using CE emulator to have an emulation of what the program will be on. I have created a skin for the device and added buttons (see xml below) that make an indication when they are pressed. I basically want to make the actual program buttons static and make the skin buttons do what the program buttons would do (cycle through menus etc). I just want to make the skin buttons act accordingly. Sorry this is really vague, I will be grateful for any help thank you.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<skin>
  <view titleBar="SalusSdk" displayWidth="480" displayHeight="272" displayPosX="147" displayPosY="103" displayDepth="16" mappingImage="down.png" normalImage="defaultskin.png" downImage="Up.png">


          <button
            toolTip="Button one"
            onClick="  DOWN:Key_LeftShift
                       Key_Z
                       0x00000015
                       UP: Key_LeftShift
                       Key_A"
            onPressAndHold="Key_B"
            mappingColor="0xFFF200"
        />


<button
            toolTip="Button two"
            onClick="  DOWN:Key_LeftShift
                       Key_Z
                       0x00000015
                       UP: Key_LeftShift
                       Key_A"
            onPressAndHold="Key_B"
            mappingColor="0x3F48CC"
        />

<button
            toolTip="Button three"
            onClick="  DOWN:Key_LeftShift
                       Key_Z
                       0x00000015
                       UP: Key_LeftShift
                       Key_A"
            onPressAndHold="Key_B"
            mappingColor="0x22B14C"
        />

<button
            toolTip="Button four"
            onClick="  DOWN:Key_LeftShift
                       Key_Z
                       0x00000015
                       UP: Key_LeftShift
                       Key_A"
            onPressAndHold="Key_B"
            mappingColor="0xFFAEC9"
        />

<button
            toolTip="Button five"
            onClick="  DOWN:Key_LeftShift
                       Key_Z
                       0x00000015
                       UP: Key_LeftShift
                       Key_A"
            onPressAndHold="Key_B"
            mappingColor="0xFF8000"
        />



<button
            toolTip="Button five"
            onClick="  DOWN:Key_LeftShift
                       Key_Z
                       0x00000015
                       UP: Key_LeftShift
                       Key_A"
            onPressAndHold="Key_B"
            mappingColor="0xA349A4"
        />     

</view>
</skin>
```

Comment: I should also mention that I have an XML file containing all the buttons and menus witht there event handlers stored in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need your application to handle the keystrokes generated by the skin's buttons.  In your skin.xml all the buttons generate the same keystroke, so you'll want to change that so they are unique.  I'd first hook up the key handling and test using the regular keyboard, then fiddle with the skin buttons to match.

Comment: Okay forgive me but I am having a bit of trouble trying to understand what to do. Do I assign that 'onClick' event to a certain keyboard key i.e. 'Home', in hexadecimal format? Then in my actual c++ code add keystrokes to the events?